# Phonegap: Retrieve all images & videos from camera roll/albums and display in a single page

Tags: cordova, phonegap-build

Is it possible ? Im trying to create a custom view for the images/videos as opposed to the default picker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah ! Definitely, you can make a custom picker. All you have to do is to modify your `HTML and CSS` for looks and deploy the `Control/Logic' in JS.

You can find a good `JS` for the same [here.](https://github.com/Arcticus/Eirene/tree/master/Image%20Picker)

Have Fun !

Comment: Thanks. It says "add it as a component to your app and remember to add pgImagePicker.js to your depends.js file". How do I go about doing this if I'm using Phonegap Build ?